# IdentityServer3 clientid and secret in plaintext in url

Tags: asp.net, identityserver3

I'm using hybrid flow from an ASP.NET MVC/WebForms project.  My redirect from the Client includes the clientId and clientSecret in plaintext in my url.

https://login.myidp.com/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=clientid&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fdemo.myrp.local%2f&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token+token&scope=openid+profile+roles+&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3dKPE-usNQD3RL79IYOnUFyaPdhDXFZQX76E989A11MXO2AM4uFFJIpy-SXA_T6XAMLQA7xBC6YlGHGC8hEkUueybPFUzyrPDGAtm0L1zEtzaZLFMtTNi3MMt0571uk_7kQwZfFDM7KdBL6K-evFZ1h8JhcgfhWGLYWcyahZc0QS_N0-H6JZb-d5gDOGchdCUCtnNwsXSaL24udJ9u9ZBfevUxttDs-nJAuBWKYUtKe5E&nonce=635806083513709419.YmI1MWM0M2MtMWMyZi00MTI1LTkwNmMtZWEwZjdiMjNkMDcxNzBlYWQ4MDUtZmUxYi00NzdlLTlhZDctZjU2NGFhNWM2NGVk&client_secret=thisismysecreta

My client setup code is very similar to the example code:

```
  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {

                ClientId = "myclientid",
                ClientSecret =  "this is my secret",
                Authority = MyConstants.IdSrv,

                RedirectUri = myurl,
                               ResponseType = "code id_token token",
                Scope = "openid profile roles "
etc.
```

This doesn't seem like a good idea.  Am I missing something amazingly obvious here?

Comment: Who puts the secret on the url. That's not needed (and obviously not recommended)

Comment: I'm not doing anything to put it there deliberately.   Is there a setting that is turned on by default?  I'm just serving up a standard 401 and the startup.UseOpenIdConnect configuration seems to take over.

Comment: Then remove it from config. You don't need it.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  My client doesn't actually need to provide a secret or client id?  Setup code is now in the question.

Comment: clientId yes - but not a secret for the authorize request.